# REGEX to check if a number is repeated in a string

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I need a regex that check if a number is repeated in a string of 9 char, knowing that the chars could be an indefinite number of dots

Examples

```
"........." - false - no numbers repeated
"123456789" - false - no numbers repeated
"1.2.3.4.5" - false - no numbers repeated
"1...3...5" - false - no numbers repeated
"112345678" - true - number 1 is repeated
"1......1." - true - number 1 is repeated
"11244.56." - true - number 1 and 4 are repeated
"234.5.6.4" - true - number 4 is repeated
```

I found this looking around on internet that is close to what i need

```
\b(?:([1-9])(?![1-9]*\1)){1,9}\b
```

But I don't know how to make it not consider dots
Thanks very much :)

Comment: Get rid of `\b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```php
^(?=.{9}$)(?=.*(\d).*\1)(?:\.*\d){1,9}\.*$
```

Or, if you need to only allow digits from `1` to `9`:

```php
^(?=.{9}$)(?=.*([1-9]).*\1)(?:\.*[1-9]){1,9}\.*$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IOcAS7/2).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.{9}$)` - the string should contain 9 chars
- `(?=.*(\d).*\1)` - there must be a repeating digit
- `(?:\.*\d){1,9}\.*` - 1 to 9 occurrences of any zero or more dots followed with a digit and then any zero or more dots
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

This regexp will allow any characters between the repeated digits:

`(\d).*\1`

`\d` matches a digit, `()` puts it in capture group 1, and the back-reference `\1` matches the same digit.